# Como remover os dias do DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datepicker

Como eu posso remover os dias do `DatePickerDialog` eu queria um calendário só com ano e mês, se alguém souber uma forma de fazer isso e poder me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

É possível, encontrei um método personalizado uma vez que remove o dia, porém não sei como ele se comporta com as versões mais atuais do `DatePicker` das novas versões do android.

```
private DatePickerDialog createDialogWithoutDateField() {

 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, null, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {

            if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(dpd);
                java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerFields = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();

                for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                    Log.i("test", datePickerField.getName());

                    if ("mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                        datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                        ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return dpd;
}
```

como esse método retorna um objeto `DatePickerDialog`, você pode passar para o seu próprio date picker ou simplesmente chamar o `show()`:

```
createDialogWithoutDateField().show();
```